# public void paint( Graphics g ) is not painting for double it is painting for string

Tags: java, eclipse

public void paint( Graphics g ) is not painting for double it is painting for string and i want to convert string to double.

So im trying to do a stack calculator and im using linked list to do it with doubles
the part for paint is not doing what i want. And what i want is that i got buttons to hold the adding and dividing etc.. and im trying to punch in a number and it would paint it right away on my window, and its not doing that. And Im using eclipse.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import NumberTree.Ornament;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class StackCalc extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    private   LinkedList<Double> values;
    double value1 , value2 ;

    JTextField theTextField;
    JButton boxButton;

    public static void main ( String[] args) {
         new StackCalc();
    }

    public StackCalc() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation( EXIT_ON_CLOSE );

        setLayout( new FlowLayout());
        setTitle("StackCalc");
        setSize(new Dimension(600,600));

        boxButton = new JButton("add");
        add(boxButton);
        boxButton.addActionListener( this );
        boxButton = new JButton("multi");
        add(boxButton);
        boxButton.addActionListener( this );
        boxButton = new JButton("divide");
        add(boxButton);
        boxButton.addActionListener( this );
        boxButton = new JButton("subt");
        add(boxButton);
        boxButton.addActionListener( this );

        theTextField = new JTextField("Write Something ");
        add(theTextField);
        theTextField.addActionListener( this );

        values = new LinkedList<Double>(); // make the stack
        setVisible(true);
  }

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if  ( e.getSource()==theTextField )  {
        value1 = Double.parseDouble(theTextField.getText());
        values.push(value1);
      }
}

public void add() {//return nothing
    value1=values.pop();
    value2=values.pop();
    values.push (value1 + value2);
}

public void multi() { //return nothing
    value1=values.pop();
    value2=values.pop();
    values.push (value1 * value2);
}

public void divide() {//return nothing
    value1=values.pop();
    value2=values.pop();
    values.push (value1 / value2);
}

public void subt() {//return nothing
    value1=values.pop();
    value2=values.pop();
    values.push (value1 - value2);
}

public void paint( Graphics g ) {
    Iterator it = values.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        double d = (Double)(it.next()); 
        Double d1 = (Double)(it.next()); 
        System.out.println("d="+d + d1 );

        super.paint(g);
        //((LinkedList) values).paint(g);
        //values = LinkedList.paint(g);

        g.create(29, 40, 100, 200); // at the bottom of the screen
        //g.drawString( value2, 50,420 ); 
       //g.drawString( values, 50,480 );    
    }
}
```

Comment: So wait, is it adding `d` and `d1` instead of concatenating them?

Comment: Your question is too unclear for me.

Comment: given 2 values, what do you expect to be printed?  right now, for values "1" and "2", this would print "D=12" (because it is "D=1" + "1" + "2" as strings.)  If you want to add the numbers, you need another set of parens: `"d=" + (d+d1)`

Comment: Could you [[edit]] your question and include example of input data, expected and real output?

Comment: um it is the super.paint(g)

Comment: after that i put values.paint(g) and it says that the method PaintGraphic is undefined for the type linkedList

Comment: and for g.drawString it says that the method drawString is in the type graphics is not applicable for the arguments (Double, int, int)

Comment: There is no method within the `Graphics` API that can paint a double..

Answer (score 1):

There is very little context to the question, making it difficult to provide a suitable answer.

Firstly, each time you call `super.paint`, you have the potential of clearing what was previously painted, making the entire loop, worthless...

Secondly, you should also avoid magic numbers where possible.

Thirdly, doing a double iteration (`it.next`) in the loop could cause a `NoSuchElementException

Fourthly, `Graphics` does not provide any means to paint anything other than a `String`, so you HAVE to convert the `double` value to a `String` value, there is no other choice...

```
public void paint( Graphics g )
{
    super.paint(g);
    FontMetrics fm = g.getFontMetrics();
    Iterator it = values.iterator();
    int width = getWidth();
    int height = getHeight();   
    int y = height;
    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        double d = (Double)(it.next()); 
        y -= fm.getHeight();
        String text = NumberFormatter.getNumberFormat().format(d);
        int x = width - fm.stringWidth(text);
        g.drawString(text, x, y + fm.getAscent());
    }
}
```

You may wish to take a look at [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) and [Working with Text APIs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) in particular.

Lastly, you should avoid overriding the `paint` method.  If you're overriding this from something like `JFrame` or `Frame`, then you should create a custom component (extending from something like `JPanel`) and place you custom painting there.  Apart from anything else, it is double buffered.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert Double to String with String.valueOf(d) and then paint it on the graphics with g.drawString method

Comment: I want to convert String to Double

Answer (score -2):

The method `public void paint(Graphics g)` gives us access to an object of the `Graphics` class. Using the object of the `Graphics` class, we can call the `drawString()` method of the `Graphics` class to write a text message in the applet window.